# How to overlap ListPlot and ArrayPlot?

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to make the points appear on the ArrayPlot? It doesn't have to be ListPlot to plot the points.

Following is the code:

```
getBaSin[x_, y_] := RandomInteger[{1, 3}]

plot1 = ArrayPlot[
  ParallelTable[
   getBaSin[x, y], {y, 0.3, -0.3, -0.1}, {x, -0.3, 0.3, 0.1}], 
  ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Green, 3 -> Blue}]
plot2 = ListPlot[{{-0.082788, 0}, {0.041394, 
    0.071696}, {0.041394, -0.071696}}]
Show[{plot1, plot2}]
```

Comment: Please create a _minimal_ example that illustrates the issue. Can you replace this with only three lines of code? Most of the code here is completely irrelevant to the question. See here for guidance. https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/what-do-we-mean-by-a-self-contained-minimal-working-example

Comment: Remove the AbsoluteTiming, then it works. You either need to rescale coordinates or use DataRange in ArrayPlot.

Comment: Is there alternative way of AbsoluteTiming in this case?

Comment: Use `a=b;//AsboluteTiming` which is equivalent to `AbsoluteTiming[a=b;]`. Do not use `a = b // AbsoluteTiming` because it is equivalent to `a = AbsoluteTiming[b]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = Table[getBaSin[x, y], {y, 0.3, -0.3, -0.1}, {x, -0.3, 0.3, 0.1}];
points = {{-0.082788, 0}, {0.041394, 0.071696}, {0.041394, -0.071696}};
ArrayPlot[mat, 
    ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Green, 3 -> Blue}, 
    DataRange -> {{-.3, .3}, {-.3, .3}}, 
    Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Large], Point @ points}, 
    FrameTicks -> All]
```

[image]